# Query condition/operator: Where id is not in array (NIN)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema of an `Object` which has a field

`helpOffers : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]`

containing many ids of users.

I'd like to find all objects where a given id, called `loggedInUserId`, is not inside `helpOffers`.

I tried `ObjectSchema.where('helpOffers').nin(loggedInUserId)...`, however this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `loggedInUserId` is a single value and not an array, you would use the [`$ne`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-ne) operator instead of `$nin` for this:

```js
ObjectSchema.where('helpOffers').ne(loggedInUserId)...
```

As a side note, `ObjectSchema` is a confusing name for your model.  It's best to keep your schemas and model naming clearly distinct.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And of course the real name of my schema is not `Object`. This was just for simplicity as the name of my schema is a domain specific name which could probably confuse you (ok, that could `Object` as well ... So next time I'll chose a better name).